# Were The Balloon Man & Spirit of the Goat Created Specifically for Gotham?

Tags: dc, gotham

After watching 28 episodes of Gotham so far (22 first season, 6 second season), I have fallen in love with the concept. Robin Lord-Taylor's portrayal of Oswald Cobblepot as he transforms into The Penguin is amazing, Cory Michael Smith makes a delightfully quirky Edward Nygma, and Ben McKenzie has shown that James Gordon is definitely in over his head, with only more problems to come.

However, as I re-watched Season 1 of Gotham, I realized that this was the only time I had ever heard of characters like The Balloon Man and The Spirit of the Goat. Are these two characters in any previous canon, perhaps Batman: The Animated Series, or possibly one-shot villains from the comics?

After all, I know that Fish Mooney was created to advance Penguin's storyline, but I just wasn't sure about these other two. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both characters were created specifically for the show. Neither have any major similarities to any past Batman villains, of any medium.

Comment: Wouldn't balloon man be kind of similar to kite man?

Comment: @CBredlow Not really. Baloonman is a vigilante who ties his victims to balloons, while Kite-man is a villain who uses kites to fly. Their methods and goals are pretty different.

Answer (score 2):

In DC comics, [Metal Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Men) do have a villain named [Balloon Man](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Balloon_Man_(Earth-One)) later known as Balloonatic Post-Crisis. But he have nothing in common except the name.

For the Spirit of the goat, [bustle.com](http://www.bustle.com/articles/46001-who-is-the-goat-on-gotham-raymond-earl-may-be-familiar-to-fans-harvey-bullock) suggests it might be inspired from [Goatboy](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Goatboy_(Prime_Earth)):-

> He could be inspired by "Goatboy," a comics villain and successful
>   assassin who hunts down and shoots the fifth Robin the Boy Wonder,
>   Damian Wayne (Bruce's son with Talia al Ghul). The two share a name
>   and a penchant for killing influential sons, but Goatboy is,
>   obviously, placed much further down on the Batman timeline

Both are long shots but still can be considered as inspiration.